# Iterating over basic blocks in reverse in LLVM Function

Tags: function, llvm, reverse-iterator

Is there any way to iterate in **reverse** on a LLVM Function. I've checked the docs
but can't seem to find any member typedef for iterating Basic blocks ( in a function ) in reverse.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Malhar

Answer (score 4):

```
for (BasicBlock::reverse_iterator i = BB->rbegin(), e = BB->rend(); i != e; ++i)
{ 
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can call [Function::getBasicBlockList()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html#ac1e61c67e6bca10ae450b722ce64a139) and then use `.rbegin()` and `rend()` on that list.

Comment: What would happen if there are 2 or more predecessor basic blocks in that case ?

Comment: Well, BBs can also have multiple descendants, so it is no different from `begin()`/`end()`. Those will be iterated in some order, I presume.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , Cant upvote it as I'm new here... Also,Just wanted to know if there is a way to initialize a basic block iterator to an Instruction* ?

Comment: LLVM doxygen documentation should help you: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ . And press green hollow mark sign to accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the **working** code snippet based on @arrowd suggestions:

```
    auto bbList = &(func_ptr->getBasicBlockList()); //fetch the pointer of the list

    errs()<<"reverse  \n";

    for(auto bb = bbList->rbegin(); bb != bbList->rend(); bb++) {

        b = &(*bb);

        errs() << b->getName()<<", ";

    }
```

> What is the sequence of printing the basic block names , in case there are multiple predecessors and successors ?

opposite of Reverse Post Order i.e Post - order (while iterating in reverse fashion)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `llvm::reverse()` from [StlExtras.h](https://llvm.org/doxygen/STLExtras_8h_source.html#l00414) to iterate containers in reverse order.